# Several Google Analytics tag on a same page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Here is my problem: our client has 2 websites, A and B.
They have 1 google analytics account with 2 properties :

- Account: CLIENTNAME
- Properties :

  - SITEA with ID UA-XXXXXX-1
  - SITEB with ID UA-XXXXXX-2

Additionally, we also have 1 analytic account with 1 property:

- Account: OURNAME
- Property :

  - SITECLIENT with ID UA-111111-1

We would like to put the client's google analytics tags on each website along with our tags (OURNAME), so that each site would have two codes.

After some searches on the support site, I found that :
"[Installing multiple instances of the Google Analytics Tracking code on a single web page is not a supported implementation](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032400&topic=1008082&ctx=topic)"

But, after searching again and trying (yes I know it's bad...), I found that it works with code like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', ACCOUNT_#1_ID],
    ['_setAllowLinker', true],
    ['_setAllowHash', false],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['b._setAccount', ' ACCOUNT_#2_ID '],
    ['b._setAllowLinker', true],
    ['b._setAllowHash', false],
    ['b._trackPageview']
```

(nothing for first tag, b for second, etc...).
So, I have few questions about theses tags because the tracking seems to be correct:

- can we skip a letter on the tracking? For example, we have 3 accounts, and we want 3 codes, a,b and d (but not c)
- can we add 2 or more tracking for one page with Google Tag Manager? (for exemple with 2 GA's type tag with the rules "for all pages")
- can I have both 1 google analytics tags and 1 GTM tag on the same page? (Not really usefull, but is it possible?)

Answer (score 1):

yes could have the more that one GA tracking code on the page of the domain.
Example for 2 GA code on the same page:

```
 <scirpt>  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)......)


    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker');

    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

more: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, the letters/names are up to you... you can prefix accounts with whatever you wish. They are there simply for individual addressing.
2. yes, though keep in mind that order in which they load can not be guaranteed. You don't need to reload the actual ga.js for each one, a single instance is fine.
3. yes, that's not an issue.

As a side note, if you are collecting data for more from more than one hostname into a single web property, you will need to set the domainname in your GA object.